# An identity of Arithmetic Functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

**Problem:** Show that for all positive integers $n$,

$$ \sum_{a=1, (a,n)=1}^{n} (a-1, n) = d(n)\phi(n)$$

where $(a, b)$ stands for $\text{gcd}(a, b)$ and $d, \phi$ are the divisor and Euler's totient function, i.e., number of numbers co-prime to n and less than n  = $\phi(n)$.

I find this one really fascinating because of $a-1$. This problem is from Niven and Zuckermann 'Introduction to the Theory of Numbers'.

My approach is to show that the L.H.S. is a multiplicative function. because it is easy to compute it for powers of primes.

Let $d_1d_2=n$ where $(d_1, d_2)=1$

I want to show that

$ \sum_{a=1, (a,n)=1}^{n} (a-1, n) =  (\sum_{a=1, (a,d_1)=1}^{d_1} (a-1, d_1))( \sum_{a=1, (a,d_2)=1}^{d_2} (a-1, d_2)) $  but I am not able to proceed other than showing that some terms are cancelling. THe main problem is that there are $x$ such that $(x, n)=1$ but $x > d_1, d_2$.

Please help. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: This is Menon's identity. P. K. Menon, On the sum $\sum(a-1,n)[(a,n)=1], J. Indian Math. Soc. (N.S.) 29 (1965) 155-163.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a divisor $d|n$, the number of $a>1$ such that $gcd(a-1,n)=d$ is equal to $|\{1 \leq q \leq \dfrac{(n-1)}{d}|(qd,n)=d\}|=|\{1 \leq q \leq \dfrac{(n-1)}{d}|(q,n/d)=1\}|=\varphi(n/d)$.
Now there's a multiplicative function.
Also, it is known that if $f$ is multiplicative, then $\sum_{d|n}f(d)$ is also muliplicative, so having an expression of this form is useful.